# python regex subsituting expression using a variable

Tags: python, regex

What I am trying to achieve is to substitute a string using python regex with a variable (contents of the variable). Since I need to retain some of the matched expression, I use the `\1` and `\3` group match args.

My regex/sub looks like this:

```
pattern = "\1" + id + "\3" \b
out = re.sub(r'(;11=)(\w+)(;)',r'%s' % pattern, line)
```

What appears to be happening is `\1` and `\3` do not get added to the output.

I have also tried this with the substitution expression:

```
r'\1%s\3'%orderid
```

But I got similar results.
Any suggestion on what might fix this?

Comment: Why do you even need to store those matches in `\1` and `\3`? They are always the same values, just put them as strings. `re.sub(r'(;11=)(\w+)(;)', ";11=" + id + ";", line)`, or remove the captures completely: `re.sub(r';11=\w+;', ";11=" + id + ";", line)` (and you don't seem to be using the `\w+` anyway).

Comment: I tried the others , but this is what worked for me eventually. Thanks Jerry. I can't believe I didn't see that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use raw strings or double the backslashes:

```
pattern = r"\1" + id + r"\3"
```

or

```
pattern = "\\1" + id + r"\\3"
```

In a regular Python string literal, `\number` is interpreted as an octal character code instead:

```
>>> '\1'
'\x01'
```

while the backslash has no special meaning in a raw string literal:

```
>>> r'\1'
'\\1'
```

Raw string literals are just a *notation*, not a type. Both `r''` and `''` produce strings, and only differ in how they interpret backslashes **in source code**.

Note that since group 1 and group3 match *literal* text, you don't need to use substitutions at all; simply use:

```
out = re.sub(r';11=\w+;', ';11=%s;' % id, line)
```

or use look-behind and lookahead and forgo having to repeat the literals:

```
out = re.sub(r'(?<=;11=)\w+(?=;)', id, line)
```

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> line = 'foobar;11=spam;hameggs'
>>> id = 'monty'
>>> re.sub(r';11=\w+;', ';11=%s;' % id, line)
'foobar;11=monty;hameggs'
>>> re.sub(r'(?<=;11=)\w+(?=;)', id, line)
'foobar;11=monty;hameggs'
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't going to work:

```
pattern = "\1" + id + "\3"
# ...
r'%s' % pattern
```

The `r` prefix only affects how the literal is interpreted. So, `r'%s'` mean that the `%` and `s` will be interpreted raw—but that's the same way they'd be interpreted without the `r`. Meanwhile, the `pattern` has non-raw literals `"\1"` and `"\3"`, so it's already a control-A and a control-C before you even get to the `%`.

What you want is:

```
pattern = r"\1" + id + r"\3"
# ...
'%s' % pattern
```

However, you really don't need the `%` formatting at all; just use `pattern` itself and you'll get the exact same thing.